# How to create Web Service using REST in Tomcat 9 + Dynamic Web Module 4

Tags: java, rest, web-services, tomcat

I cant figure it out why the code below is not working in dynamic module 4 + tomcat 9. I try to create first Web Service based on REST without web.xml so that I have two classes:

```
@ApplicationPath("/packme")
public class PackMeWSApplication extends Application{}
```

and one service class:

```
@Path("/returnOrder")
public class CreateReturnOrderService {

   @Path("/getData")
   @GET
   public String getData() {
      return "IT IS FINALLY WORKING!!!";
   }
}
```

and then the code is published on local server (tomcat 9, tried to restart, clean etc...) and I tried to call it via address:
http://localhost:8080/PackMeWS/packme/returnOrder/getData

and the response ist HTTP 404 - not found (PackMeWS - this is the context/application name).

I am new in Web Services and followed several tutorials (but those tutorials referred to tomcat v8 or below and dynamic module 3.1)

Comment: whatever's wrong is "something simple". I suspect it's just an incorrect path.  Q: What IDE (if any) are you using?  SUGGESTION: If you happen to be using Eclipse, try this tutorial: [REST with Java (JAX-RS) using Jersey - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html).  Install the latest/greatest Java, Eclipse, Tomcat - whatever you want.  But follow the instructions carefully.  It *SHOULD* work.

Comment: this tutorial refers to some older version and web.xml is still in use and there vogella used gradle, I use maven. The IDE I use is Eclipse + Java 1.8. I wish I could check all the established REST endpoints somehow (like in SOAP WS)

Comment: ARGH!!!!  Ignore the irrelevancies, and try the tutorial.  That should absolutely show you "what you're missing" (again - undoubtedly something "simple", like a redundant @Path annotation, or unnecessary path elements in your URL).  IMHO...

Answer (score 0):

ok the problem was in pom.xml as maven is used in this project, I replaced line:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

with line:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

and it started working